# Preventing 'enumerating whilst mutating' error in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
dispatch_async(self._queue, {
    // Remove old stops
    for (var i = 0; i < self.activeStops.count; i++) {
        if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.activeStops[i].coordinate))) {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(self.activeStops[i])
            self.activeStops.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
    }

    // Add new stops
    for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++) {
        if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position))) {
            let stop: StopAnnotation! = StopAnnotation()
            stop.setCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)
            stop.bearing = self.busStops[i].bearing
            stop.name = self.busStops[i].name
            stop.lines = self.busStops[i].lines
            stop.atcocode = self.busStops[i].atcocode
            self.activeStops.append(stop)
        }
    }

    // Add new stops to map
    dispatch_async(self._queue, {
        self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.activeStops)
        self.isUpdatingMap = false
    })
})

self.nearestStopsTable.reloadData()
```

What I would like to do and what I am trying to do in the above code is remove bus stops that are no longer visible on the screen and then continue by adding new ones.

The problem is with my current approach, I am enumerating the array whilst it is being mutated therefore it is throwing an error.

I am assuming this is because I am removing from the `activeStops` array whilst it is looping through it.

How can I change my code so that it doesn't generate this error?

Comment: What is the EXACT error message?  On what line does it occur?  (The loop on activeStops should not generate such a message, though it will fail.  The way to fix it is to loop backwards.)

Comment: My suggetion is iterating over a copy of the array that is to be changed. Refer to the copy in the if statement and manipulate the original. Iterate descending (start with `i=copyOfActiveStops.count` and go on with `i>0, <--` . Doing so you will achieve the same as Shai corretly suggests, but it may be less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < self.activeStops.count; i++) {
        if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.activeStops[i].coordinate))) {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(self.activeStops[i])
            self.activeStops.removeAtIndex(i)
        }
    }
```

You're mutating activateStops in the middle of the iteration

Instead of removing objects while iterating, you can do the following:

```
var indicesToRemove : NSMutableIndexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()

for (var i = 0; i < self.activeStops.count; i++) {
    if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.activeStops[i].coordinate))) {
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(self.activeStops[i])
        indicesToRemove.addIndex(i);
    }
}

self.activeStops.removeObjectsAtIndexes(indicesToRemove)
```

Comment: Removing the elements in ascending order can easily fail, because removing one element changes the indices of the remaining elements ...

Comment: @MartinR yep, made an edit that makes use of NSIndexSet

Comment: You could also write this using the array method `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` or `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:`, and pass in a block that evaluates each stop. That would make the code to create the indexSet shorter, and the form with the options parameter supports concurrency, which would speed up the search.

Comment: @Shai My array is an NSArray. How would you recommend I get around this? `removeObjectsAtIndexes` belongs to NSMutableArray

Comment: if your array is immutable, then how did you plan on using 'removeAtIndex' at first place (originally in your question)? :-) What you could to is to create a mutable copy of self.activeStops, remove the relevant objects, and then re-assign self.activeStops